# How to access the real and imaginary part of complex number in perl?

Tags: perl, math, complex-numbers

as I told I am new to perl. I am working on complex numbers,
I use

```
 use Math::Complex;
```

for complex numbers,
and this is my code,

```
     for($k=0;$k<$N;$k++)
   {
    $c[k]= Math::Complex->new(0,0);
    for ($n=0;$n<($N-1);$n++)
    {
       $c[k]=$c[k] + ( $we[($k * $n)% $N] * $y[n]) ;
    }
  }
```

Now How to access only the real part or imaginary part of complex numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](http://search.cpan.org/~zefram/Math-Complex-1.59/lib/Math/Complex.pm), you can use `Re(z)` and `Im(z)` to get to the real and imaginary parts.